# How meteor enforce that queries that share same records are updated in same time?

Tags: meteor

if i publish two sources:

1. **newest-message:** this will be always the newest message
2. **messages:** this can be parametrized by interval (for pagination). For instance **messages 1-10** will be 10 newest messages.

On my site, i will show the **newest-message** and **messages** separately, but in same screen.

**Question:** It can happen that **newest-message** and **messages** will share exactly one record (in case user is subscribed to **newest-message** and **messages [1..N]**). How meteor enforce that if i have two queries, one leading to record from **newest-message** and one to records from **messages 1-10** (results of these queries will share one record - the newest message), these reactive sources will be updated **SAME TIME**, so it does not happend that user will see there is **new newest message**, but still not noticed this message in message area where **first 10 newest messages** are shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the mongodb server updates the records the minimongo on the client will replicate the update using the mongo oplog, once the minimongo client replicates said changes all of the templates that need re-evaluating will be updated.

So in a nutshell, don't worry, Meteor will make sure all of the templates will refresh at the same time.